# Strange behaviour of is_user_logged_in() and get_current_user_id()

Tags: htaccess, security, membership

I have an issue where `is_user_logged_in()` appears to alternate between being true and false.

Additionally, `get_current_user_id()` gives the correct user ID if `is_user_logged_in()` is true.

Here's my code:

.htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ file-access.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

file-access.php:

```
require_once('wp-load.php');

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // User is logged in, proceed.
} else {
    // User is a guest, block.
}
```

I've verified the alternating status and user id using some error logging in the `file-access.php` conditionals.

Do I need to call something other than wp-load.php perhaps? Just seems strange to me that it alternates between true and false, rather than always being false...

Edit to add: I also had an issue where one of my files I was testing with wasn't uploaded as the https version which caused issues.

Comment: Is it possible this function is being called too early? Maybe you try to invoke it via init hook so when it is called all pre requisite have been loaded.  See the second comment in docs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/ about being a pluggable function and calling it init action hook...

Comment: Is the URL changing (scheme / domain www vs non-www / URL-path) in a way that prevents the authentication cookie being sent? eg. If you logged in at `www.example.com`, then you won't necessarily be logged in at `example.com` - depending on how the cookies were set.

Comment: @Mohsin good thought, but if I wrap it like that it doesn't run at all.

Comment: @MrWhite no, it's on a subdomain anyway so www version doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run your code and it works fine to me except for  the inclusion in file-access.php:

`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');` 
enable debug to see if there are errors depending on other issues and not regarding these specific code lines.

But.. as per WP documentation: [actions reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request) the earlier action hook where the authentication process is completed and cookies are set is `init` as suggested in [@Mohsin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/30852/mohsin)  comment so I suggest to use this code in *file-access.php*

```
/* you probably don't need a theme */ 
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 

/* defining a constant here allows you to exit functions when not needed */
define('FROM_EXTERNAL_FILE',true);

/* unless you've renamed your wp-content folder this path will always point to wp-load.php even in subfolders installations */
require_once(explode("wp-content", __FILE__)[0] . "wp-load.php");
```

and move the check in your file functions.php which gets loaded with the whole WP environment by *wp-load.php*

```
function is_logged_function(){
  if ( !defined ('FROM_EXTERNAL_FILE') )
    return;
  if ( is_user_logged_in()){
    echo "logged";
    echo get_current_user_id();
  }
  else{
    echo "not logged";
  }
}
add_action('init', 'is_logged_function');
```

Answer (score 0):

The file that would normally be called to kick off the Wordpress setup is wp-blog-header.php so maybe try swapping out `wp-load.php` for `wp-blog-header.php` in your code then re-test

Comment: Hmm- doesn't work, same result weirdly enough.

Comment: Mmm weird. Are you load balancing traffic across multiple servers or databases? Just wondering if something on the backend is getting out of sync somewhere